# add a an extra row in the outcome

Tags: sql, string, oracle, pivot

I have a ORACLE sql query that needs to add a header (Only one row) with the name of the columns in the outcome.
How could that be achieved?

```
1-1-2022 08:32:00   xxx1    166 1   04641127    8   1
1-1-2022 07:05:00   xxx1    167 1   10205792    8   1
1-1-2022 09:20:00   xxx1    176 1   10256841    8   1
1-1-2022 10:10:00   xxx1    177 1   10193856    8   1
```

Regards

```
Date                dep    room nr   rec       type count
6-4-2022 08:32:00   xxx1    166 1   04641127    8   1
6-4-2022 07:05:00   xxx1    167 1   10205792    8   1
5-4-2022 09:20:00   xxx2    176 1   10256841    8   1
5-4-2022 10:10:00   xxx2    177 1   10193856    8   1
```

Comment: Don't do this in SQL. Do it in the client application (SQL*Plus, Java, PHP, etc.) that you are using to access the database using whatever method is appropriate for that client application. If you try doing it in SQL then you will have to change all the columns to a string data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` is one option; note that - in that case - both `SELECT` statements have to share the same **number of columns** and their **datatypes**.

Something like this:

```
select 'Date' col1, 'dep' col2, 'room' col3, 'nr' col4, 'rec' col5, 'type' col6, 'count' col7
from dual
union all
select to_char(date_column, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 
  dep, 
  to_char(room), 
  to_char(nr),
  rec,
  to_char(type), 
  to_char(count_column)
from some_table
```